# POST 400 (BAD REQUEST) when uploading file between React and Flask

Tags: reactjs, flask

Keep getting a 400 error when uploading an excel file in my react front end and passing it to a flask api.

The flask backend route is as such:

```
    def post(self):
        name = request.form['name']
        file = request.files['file']
        (....do stuff with file and name)
```

The react API call is as follows:

```
export const uploadFile = async (file) => {

    const data = new FormData()
    data.append("file", file)
    data.append("name", 'temp')

    const api_url = "http://localhost:5000/uploadFile"
    const settings = {        
        method: "POST",
        body: data
    }

    try {
        const response = await fetch(api_url, settings)
        const result = await response.json()
        if (result.message === 'OK') {
            return result
        }
    } catch (error) {
        return "Unable to load file"
    }
}
```

Interesting the NAME field is getting received by Flask but the file object for some reason is not being processed by Flask.

I've tried adding a `multi-part/formdata` Content-Type in the React Fetch API call as well, but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the issue.

Turns out you need to pass the `[0]` following in the React call:

`data.append("file", file[0])`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to post an image file to Flask just using a vanilla JS `fetch` call, and @Anubhav's answer helped me realise that I needed to use FormData, rather than just posting the file/blob as the `body`. In case someone is looking for some full, working example code:

```html
<input type="file" id="fileEl"/>
```

```js
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", fileEl.files[0]);

let response = await fetch("http://example.com/upload", {
  method: "POST",
  body: formData,
}).then(r => r.json());
```